# Stress Test question

Tags: dell

I am a newbie, and am busy converting to Linux after seeing my friend work on it.

I bought a second hand cheap machine from a lady at my work, it runs, I just want to stress test to see that nothing fails.

I have read the stress function and have installed it.

My question is, what would be the best test for this core 2 dell optiplex 755, it has 3gb of ram and a 160gb hard HDD.

I found this and wonder if it would be good to run.

stress -c 2 -m 2 -d 1 -t 40s

Answer (score 0):

stress is a command line tool that forces an amount of CPU, memor or disk stress on the system. This is done to report errors and give developers an idea of how their system could scale. With that in mind and knowing this is NOT a benchmark tool, the correct stress level depends on your hardware.

On your case `-c 2` & `-m 2` is enough for the CPU you are using. I normally don't like stressing the hard drive with the `-d` option since it takes away life from it (Leech king style). you could however add the `-i` option for the I/O and lower the `-t` paremeter to 10 to 20 seconds.

Comment: Thank You, If I understand correctly -c 2 is for 2 processors? I am very confused, some scripts i ses say --cpu 2? so if I say stress -c 2 -m 2 -i 4 -t 20s this will be correct?